# Define function / method if not defined before c++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, methods, precompile

I don't use C++11 yet, so I wrote the functions `to_string(whatever)` by myself. They should only be compiled if they don't exist. If I switch to C++11, they should be skipped. I have something like this:

```
#ifndef to_string

string to_string(int a){
    string ret;
    stringstream b;
    b << a;
    b >> ret;
    return ret;
}

string to_string(double a){
    string ret;
    stringstream b;
    b << a;
    b >> ret;
    return ret;
}

#endif
```

This doesn't work apparently. Is something like this possible and if yes, how?

Comment: It works pre-C++11, See http://cpp.sh/86ldr

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Well, it shouldn't work. `std::to_string` is C++11 thing

Comment: Personally I think it's a very bad practice, and there is no good answer to this question. C++ standard doesn't provice `to_string`, but `std::to_string`, which is very different. That means, you can't use `std::to_string` if your standard doesn't support it. Now think again - let's assume that you already use C++11. What now? If you use macro from accepted answer, will you for the rest of your life use it instead of `std::to_string`? Very, very bad idea.

Comment: The reason that it doesn't work is that `#ifdef` only tests the presence of _preprocessor_ definitions, not of regular functions like `std::to_string`. And this is all that `#ifdef` can test, as preprocessor directives are executed by the ... preprocessor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is one of main purpose of [`namespace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) existence.

My suggest is to include your personal function in a proper namespace, something like:

```
namespace myns {
  std::string to_string(...) {
    // ...
  }
  // etc...
}
```

This is fundamental in order to avoid future conflict problems.

Afterwards, when you're going to use that function, you can simple select the proper function with a `MACRO` substitution.

Something like:

```
#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) 
  #define my_tostring(X) std::to_string(X)
#else
  #define my_tostring(X) myns::to_string(X)
#endif
```

Note `__cplusplus` is a *[pre-defined macro](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Standards/)* which contains compiling information about standard version.

---

**Edit:**
Something less "violent", it will select the proper namespace for that specific function in accordance with the standard version:

```
#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) 
  using std::to_string;
#else
  using myns::to_string;
#endif

// ... somewhere
to_string(/*...*/);  // it should use the proper namespace
```

Comment: `#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) ` is what I needed. Thank's man.

Comment: Rather than  #define a macro, put an appropriate `using `ns`::to_string` in each branch of the `#ifdef` block.  Less violence to your compiler name space.

Answer (score 9):

You can't test whether they're defined as such, but you can check the language version:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
```

(There's a useful collection of predefined compiler macros [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/).)

Answer (score 2):

You could play with SFINAE having in mind that non-template overloads are preferred over the template ones. This compiles in both pre-c++11 and c++11:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace my {
   template <bool V, class T>
   struct enable_if {
   };

   template <class T>
   struct enable_if<true, T> {
      typedef T type;
   };

   template <class T1, class T2>
   struct is_same {
      static const bool value = false;
   };

   template <class T>
   struct is_same<T, T> {
      static const bool value = true;
   };
}

template <class T>
typename my::enable_if<my::is_same<T, int>::value
                      || my::is_same<T, double>::value, string>::type
  to_string(T const& a) {
    string ret;
    stringstream b;
    b << a;
    b >> ret;
    return ret;
}

int main() {
   cout << to_string(2) << endl;
   cout << to_string(3.4) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your functions inside a macro, like this:

```
#ifndef to_string
#define to_string

//....

#endif
```

Then, in another file, write this:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    #undef to_string
#else
    #define to_string
#endif
```

Comment: The code doesn't need to check whether `to_string` is defined; `#undef` can be used with names that have not been defined.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) has some [macros](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported) to check whether C++11 features are supported/used.

Comment: I don't see a macro for the `to_string` functions in this list though.